# OpenZeppelin Initializable Error "Initializable: contract is not initializing" when calling initialize function for the first time

Tags: hardhat, openzeppelin, hardhat-deploy, upgrading, contract-upgrading

I have a contract that "is Initializable" and it is the base contract so I am using the `onlyInitializing` modifier. However, after I deploy my contract and call the initialize function I receive "Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Initializable: contract is not initializing'"
I am using hardhat deploy.
My initialize function

```
   function initialize(
        IERC20 _token,
        uint256 _maxDuration,
        uint256 _minDuration
    ) public onlyInitializing {
        token = _token;
        maxDuration = _maxDuration;
        minDuration = _minDuration;
    }
```

and here is some of my deploy script where I hit the error

```typescript
   await deploy('Crowdfund', {
      from: deployer,
      log: true,
      waitConfirmations: waitBlockConfirmations
    });

    log('Initializing Crowdfund');

    crowdfund = await ethers.getContract('Crowdfund');
    const initTx = await crowdfund.initialize(
      initArgs.tokenAddress,
      initArgs.min_duration,
      initArgs.max_duration
    );
    initTx.wait(1);

    log('Crowdfund initialized');
```

[FULL REPO](https://github.com/K-G-J/metacrafters-crowdfund)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `initializer()` modifier instead of `onlyInitializing()`. `initializer()` is used in the top-level initialize call, `onlyInitializing()` only in functions called inside it.

```
    function initialize(
        IERC20 _token,
        uint256 _maxDuration,
        uint256 _minDuration
    ) public initializer {
        token = _token;
        maxDuration = _maxDuration;
        minDuration = _minDuration;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Why is it that when I use the initializer modifier I am able to call the initialize function on my contract more than once? Shouldn't I only be able to call the function with at modifier once?

Comment: @KateJohnson Yeah, the second time should revert. It's possible that there's a bug in your deploy/test scripts. Try making all transactions in the same function, one after the other, calling `initialize` two times and it should behave as expected.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't revert but when I used both modifiers it did revert as expected